# Traversing through a custom List of Object java

Tags: java

I have a custom list of entity objects:

```
List<Student> lstStudents
```

The list has data from the database.

How do I traverse through this list and output each data element/column.

I tried this:

```
for (final Student s: lstStudents) 
{
    outputTDCFile=outputTDCFile+s.getID();
    System.out.println(s.getID());
}
System.out.println(outputTDCFile);
```

I am getting an empty result.

Issue seems to be with System.out.println(outputTDCFile);
Even though the outputTDCFile variable is populated with the values the System.out.println fails to print it.

[image]

Comment: so outputTDCFile is empty or s.getDriverID() ?

Comment: so your input is empty =))

Comment: I dont know what "result" refers to.   Is the inner println being fired?   If it is the empty string, you might not see it in your console.

Comment: place a break point at for statement and make sure Student "s" has valid data in it.

Comment: you are traversing correctly, possibility is your `lstStudents` contains no Student object in it. And your outputTDCFile is declared as `String outputTDCFile = "";`

Comment: Looks like you should have a look at the code populating your list. The traversal is correct.

Comment: System.out.println(s.getDriverID()); is outputting IDs but the System.out.println(outputTDCFile); is not. I think have to debug more.

Answer (score 0):

I see these possibilities.

1. lstStudents is empty
2. getID() returns empty string
3. Standard output is redirected

I think that number one is most probable.

Solution:
Either debug your code with a breakpoints or use this snippet to see if lstStudents contains something to be processed.

```
if (lstStudents.isEmpty())
{
    System.out.println("lstStudents is empty");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("lstStudents is not empty, problem is elsewhere");
}

for (final Student s: lstStudents) 
{
    outputTDCFile=outputTDCFile+s.getID();
    System.out.println(s.getID());
}
System.out.println(outputTDCFile);
```

If nothing is displayed, then you might have some problem with standard output.

Comment: The issue is 3. The output is not print to screen. Not sure why.